How to format an external drive into encrypted exFAT in Windows 11?
My current USB drive (256gb) is formatted in Mac and is an encrypted APFS file system made in Disk Utility. I recently started using Windows 11 and I would like to transfer and access files between Windows and Mac. I am also getting a 2tb external SSD (usb-c) to use as a larger backup disk.
How can I encrypt my USB drive and external SSD so that those can be accessed by both Windows and Mac?

Windows has zero support for APFS. MacOS and Windows both support Veracrypt and exFAT.

Unless storing very large media files, exFAT would not be recommended because it's a purpose-built filesystem specifically designed to store large video and photo files - I explain why in this and this comment. ext3/4 would likely be recommended since Windows and Mac both support the filesystem with software (Windows: WSL or Paragon's LinuxFS)
